# ANR in my app if no internet connection available

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am having a little problem, I can connect to internet and read an url easily. but if no internet connection is available I get ANR and my app is force closed !
Any help ?

```
    try {
        URL Url = new URL(url); 
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();


        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //httpCon.setReadTimeout(2000);
        Log.v("Parser","before connect");
        //httpCon.connect(); 
        int response;
            response = httpCon.getResponseCode();

        } catch (Exception urlExc) {
            Log.v("Parser","into parser error" + urlExc.getCause());
            return false;
        }
```

When no connection available, it is forced closed instead of going to catch()

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in the main UI thread? If so, don't. Investigate one of the many ways of using background threads.

See this [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article for a discussion. It says:

> Specifically, if everything is happening in a single thread,
>   performing long operations such as network access or database queries
>   on the UI thread will block the whole user interface. No event can be
>   dispatched, including drawing events, while the long operation is
>   underway. From the user's perspective, the application appears hung.
>   Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds
>   (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous
>   "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

([ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) might be a good starting point.)